# Where to find Programming Ebooks in epub/mobi format?

Tags: ebook-management, programming

From where can I download programming/coding or any book related to computer science. I am trying to have a collection of epub/mobi/azw3 programming/computer science books. Is there any site for that or can anyone share me those ? I don't want pdf because they are almost impossible to read on kindle.

Comment: Which Kindle are you using? Also, are you using the Kindle app to read the PDFs . Or are you downloading a separate PDF app?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not on topic here - as the help on topic doc says "Shopping-style questions are also discouraged (e.g. Where can I find free ebooks about subject abc?"

Answer (score 4):

Depends on a lot of things.

First, are you using an eink version of a kindle? or a Kindle Fire?

If you are using e-ink (and therefore can't use pdf easily), I would recommend buying ebooks from Oreilly or Packt Publishing. They're very expensive, but at least they will format properly for an eink device.

(by the way, both companies have pretty good sales (and occasional free downloads), so I would recommend signing up for their email list.

If you have a Kindle Fire, then all you need to do is to download a PDF reader app (there are many -- don't try to read things  with the Kindle app).

You may be limited by what you can afford, but because PDFs are not reflowable, you want to get a fairly good screen size to read them. You need at least 8 inch screen in my opinion. If you buy smaller, the text size will be hard to read. (There's a zoom function in smaller devices, but it's inconvenient).

Try http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/ for a good (and famous) introduction to basic structures (using python as an example). I recommend this for starting out. Here's the pdf of the latest version http://www.ict.ru.ac.za/Resources/cspw/thinkcspy3/

(Older editions of this book in other computer languages are here: http://www.openbookproject.net/thinkcs/archive/ ).

Here's a list of ebooks for free out there 
https://github.com/vhf/free-programming-books/blob/master/free-programming-books.md

One more thing. If you have kindle fire, I would sign up for evernote, download the app on your tablet and then clip recent web tutorials on subjects which interest you. this is a good way to read articles when offline; evernote renders the content pretty well.

Finally, I want to really recommend buying a tablet which you can be comfortable reading PDFs on. 6 or 7 inch tablets just aren't good enough for most people to read PDFs on. I have an ipad 1 with the 10 inch screen and I still use it for reading technical manuals.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I own kindle voyage , that's why I said I don't require pdf , I am looking for .epub , .mobi or .azw3 format technical/programming books.

Comment: The problem is that you will find very few free ebooks which are formatted properly for e-ink devices like the Voyager. (Oreilly books and Packt books do so well, but not too many others). You might check out the programming books on Smashwords (and sort by free) by the formatting for these books might not be good. (and also the smashwords ebooks are generally of lower quality -- though there are many exceptions). https://www.smashwords.com/books/category/655

Comment: All the smashwords books are converted into .mobi format, so theoretically they should look ok (and btw, no DRM on any of them). But practically speaking you won't know until you download it.

Comment: Please do not answer shopping-style questions here; it only encourages them, and they are not the kinds of question this site is for.